# Error in OnItemClickListener in ListView IN Android

Tags: android, listview

I have following line in my activity class .

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterViewCompat<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

And eclipse gives me the following error :

```
The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener(){})
```

Why am I getting this error ? Please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below import to your code

```
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

instead of the below import

```
 import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 1):

You have imported the wrong listener, check your import for

`AdapterViewCompat.OnItemClickListener`

and replace it with

```
android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
```